# Ensure that g++ does not compile a program using features added in newer versions of C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, g++

Compiling with the flag `-std=c++14` compiles programs which use features implemented in newer versions of C++ as well, issuing a warning like the following:

```
warning: inline variables are only available with -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17
```

I don't want g++ to compile the program in this situation and do not know why it does in the first place.

I found out that adding the flag `-Werror` converts the above warning to an error, ensuring that the program does not compile but I am not sure whether that is the recommended way to do so.

Comment: I'd say that is the way to do it.

Comment: Yes using `-Werror` is the recommended way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provoke compiler errors specifically for the use of language features that are legal only
in C++ standards later than your chosen one, the best-targeted diagnostic option
is probably `-pedantic-errors`, which is [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

> -pedantic-errors
>
> **Give an error whenever the base standard (see -Wpedantic) requires a diagnostic**, in some cases where there is undefined behavior at compile-time and in some other cases that do not prevent compilation of programs that are valid according to the standard...

[my emphasis]

The "base standard" here is the C++ standard named by the specified or default value of `-std=...` (or if that one is a GNU dialect like `gnu++14`, then it is the C++ standard on which that dialect is based).

If you compile source code with, say, `std=c++14` that uses a construct first legalised in C++17, then that code is ill-formed per the C++14 standard and a diagnostic is required.
The addition of `-pedantic-errors` to `-std=c++14` will therefore oblige the compiler to diagnose the C++17 innovations as errors.

E.g, without `-pedantic-errors`

```
$ cat foo.cpp
struct foo
{
    inline static const int value = 42;
};

$ g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c foo.cpp
foo.cpp:3:5: warning: inline variables are only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
    3 |     inline static const int value = 42;
      |     ^~~~~~
```

And with `-pedantic-errors`

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -c foo.cpp
foo.cpp:3:5: error: inline variables are only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
    3 |     inline static const int value = 42;
      |     ^~~~~~
```

`-pedantic-errors` will make the compiler more fussy about C++14 conformity than
`std-c++14` by itself, or with `-Werror`. But I guess you won't object to that. And you can make an unconstrained
choice as to whether you also practice the blanket discipline of compiling with zero warnings (`-Werror`)